# Segmentation fault (with file on C)

Tags: c

I want to create a file that has a name such the example: module_extension/user.txt :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   char example[100];
   char user[100]="user";
   char str[]="module_extension/";
   FILE* fichier=NULL;


   strcpy(example,str);
   strcat(example,user);
   strcat(example,".txt");
   fichier=fopen(example,"a+");
   fprintf(fichier,"**************New Line************ \n");
   fclose(fichier);

   return 0;
}
```

But when I run it I got this error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you checked the result of `fopen`? Of course you haven't...

Comment: I don't have the file,it didn't been created.

Comment: "result" = return value.

Comment: For that matter, throw out everything but the `fopen` (which you should check), the `fprintf`, and the `fclose`. You gotta isolate your problem before you can fix it.

Comment: I don't understand what you say,please explain more.

Comment: @bindingbinding Functions have return values (unless they are `void`). Their meaning can be found in their documentation.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I comment the lines containing fprintf and fclose but I got the same problem "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Which makes a perfect sense. Well, *clairvoyance mode on*. You don't have a subdirectory called `module_extension` in the directory you are running it from.

Comment: @EugeneSh:I don't have any directory only test.c test.o

Comment: So how do you expect `fopen` to create a file in a non-existent directory?

Comment: I fix the problem,you are right @EugeneSh I don't have a directory,I modify the str and this works.thank you.

Comment: @bindingbinding The comments about the return value checking are still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What people are trying to point at in the comments is. When a system call is made, the return value should be checked, to make sure if it was executed successfully or not. In your case, the `open` system call can fail for a number of reasons. In that case you would have an invalid file descriptor in the variable `fichier`. Using which can result into a `seg fault`, which you are getting.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   char example[100];
   char user[100]="user";
   char str[]="module_extension/";
   FILE* fichier=NULL;


   strcpy(example,str);
   strcat(example,user);
   strcat(example,".txt");
   fichier=fopen(example,"a+");
   if( fichier != NULL)
   {
       fprintf(fichier,"**************New Line************ \n");
       fclose(fichier);
   }
   else
       printf("File open failed");

   return 0;
}
```

In this way, you can make your program fail proof, even when the system call fails.